# Built-in angular timepicker and datepicker not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I tried to use the built-in angular timepicker and datepicker for my app. BUT I notice it works fine in google chrome as the datepicker and timepicker are shown but not in Firefox and IE. I notice even the example on the website itself not working for Firefox and IE. The examples are:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Why does it happened? It does not support for firefox and IE? Any workaround? Or is there any other plugin that is supported for the 3 browsers that I can use?

Comment: the built in date-time picker has nothing to do with angular, they are browsers implementation of `type="date"` and `type="time"`, hence if it does not work problem is with browser's. Better use angular-ui date/time pickers for the job

Comment: The is some text at the top of the page on each of those links that explains that it will only work on browsers that support the HTML5 date input. An alternative that you could try would be jquery.